# Using OR patterns in shell wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ls, wildcards

Contents of my dir are

```
$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 admin 19 Oct  8 12:31 night.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 admin 19 Oct  8 12:31 noon.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 admin 38 Oct  8 12:31 day.txt
```

I would like to list out details of files that have a word in the filename as specified.

#### Example :

```
$ ls -lrt *day|night*
ls: *day: No such file or directory
bash: night.txt: command not found
```

#### Expected output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 admin 19 Oct  8 12:31 night.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 admin 38 Oct  8 12:31 day.txt
```

How to list out different files matching 2 different partterns, or in short how to use regex with `ls`, so that I could `OR` the filename parts.

Original scenarion, there are many file in the directory, have shortened the case for asking.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You don't even need extended globbing enabled to do what you want.  This will work in bash:

```
ls {day*,night*}
```

Comment: No it doesn't: `touch day.txt; touch night.txt; ls {*day,night*}` results in `ls: *day: No such file or directory`

Comment: I was adapting the original poster's text; I thought that was clear.  *sigh*.  Text updated.  Surely you can see that the *mechanism* works?

Comment: Or possibly `*{day,night}*` is closer to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 34):

There is no option in `ls` to filter on filename but in most of the shells there are globbing extension `man bash` `/Pattern Matching`

ksh

```
ls -lrtd -- *@(day|night)*
```

zsh

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -lrtd -- *(day|night)*
```

or:

```
setopt kshglob
ls -lrtd -- *@(day|night)*
```

bash

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -lrtd -- *@(day|night)*
```

In any of these three shells you can do this, but note that if one of the cases doesn't match any file, that pattern will be left unexpanded (e.g. `*day* night1.txt othernight.txt` if there is no file name containing `day`; see `man bash` `/EXPANSION` or `/Brace Expansion` specifically):

```
ls -lrtd -- *{day,night}*
```

In any shells you can do:

```
ls -lrtd -- *day* *night*
```

In zsh, if there's either no `day` or `night` file, the last two commands will fail; set the `nonomatch` or `csh_null_glob` option, or add `(N)` after each pattern to avoid this.

Comment: What about `*{day,night}*`. I'd edit it, but I don't know which shells support it?

Comment: @Random832 Works in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` (none need extended globbing), but not `sh` - however, Nahuel's last "all shells" example does work in `sh`.

Answer (score 15):

Shells do not uses regular expressions for argument expansion.

You can enable the extended pattern matching by

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

and then

```
$ ls @(day|night).txt
day.txt   night.txt
```

See for example the [Bash Reference Manual (Pattern Matching)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Answer (score -2):

You can pipe `ls` with `grep` as below

```
aashutosh@ubuntu:/tmp$ ls -ltrh
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aashutsh user 0 May  9 02:55 noon.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aashutsh user 0 May  9 02:55 night.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aashutsh user 0 May  9 02:55 day.txt

aashutosh@ubuntu:/tmp$ ls -ltr | grep 'night\|day'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aashutsh user 0 May  9 02:55 night.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aashutsh user 0 May  9 02:55 day.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that would also pick up on file entries where e.g. the owning user or group contains `day` or `night`, not only the filename.